Как выполнить скрипт по окончании его вставки через document.head.appendChild(my_script)?
У меня возникла вот такая трудность.
Я пользуюсь загрузкой скрипта (и добавлением его на страницу) при помощи такого кода:
    var my_script = document.createElement('script');
    my_script.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
    my_script.setAttribute('src','https://mysite.ru/storage/script.js');
    document.head.appendChild(my_script);
    function_onload();

При этом последня строка function_onload() - это вызов функции, которая уже находится в загруженном скрипте.
И на этой строке я получаю ошибку
    polyfills-es5.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: function_onload is not defined

Ну, понятно.
Операция добавления скрипта ( document.head.appendChild(my_script) ) - асинхронная, и в тот момент, когда я вызываю функцию function_onload - она еще не завершилась.
я пробовал разные подходы:
писал
    my_script.async = false;

до вызова my_script.setAttribute, ( это ни на что не повлияло )
пробовал переписать последнюю строку в стиле
    document.head.appendChild(my_script)
    .then ( () => function_onload() );

При этом я получил другую ошибку - TypeError: document.head.appendChild(...).then is not a function
Можно, конечно, "завести будильник" (поставить таймер), но это очень ненадёжное решение...
Что можно сделать в такой ситуации? как понять, что скрипт уже загрузился и готов к выполнению?
Спасибо.

Пробуй так my_script.addEventListener('load', _ => function_onload())

Йес! Йес! Это работает! Не хотитет оформить, как ответ? Спасибо!!

Операция добавелния скрипта ( document.head.appendChild(my_script) ) - асинхронная - это неверно, как раз добавление - синхронное

@Grundy - спасибо за замечание, Вы не раз помогали мне на этом форуме. перечитал ответ, понял, что нужно привязываться к событию load у элемента document.createElement('script')


Что можно сделать в такой ситуации? как понять, что скрипт уже загрузился и готов к выполнению?

У самого элемента document.createElement('script') есть событие load. Оно "срабатывает" как раз после загрузки скрипта.
Все что тебе остается - навесить обработчик, который и вызовет (уже загруженную) функцию. Что-то типа такого...
my_script.addEventListener('load', _ => function_onload())


У меня возникло усложнение задачи, которое было связано вот с чем:
в примере, который есть в вопросе (и в ответе) у скрипта есть атрибут 'src'.
И загрузка скрипта происходит с некого URL-адреса.
А когда код будет загружен - то нужно запустить одну из функций внутри этого кода.
И в этом случае для запуска надо использовать событие 'load' и "вешаться" на него с помощью
my_script.addEventListener('load', _ => function_onload());

Но что, если загрузка скрипта из внешнего источника не предполагается?
Оказывется, при этом задача как бы "упрощается", но... событие 'load' больше не работает!
в этом случае все проще:
Пускай у нас есть тело скрипта (в переменной my_script_body). Тогда делаем примерно так:
<html>
<head>
    <script>

    function body_onload(){
        var my_script_body = 'function myScriptFunction(){ alert(\'Hi from myScriptFunction!\'); }';
        var my_script = document.createElement('script');
        my_script.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
        //my_script.innerText = my_script_body;
        my_script.innerHTML = my_script_body;
        document.head.appendChild(my_script);
        myScriptFunction();
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload='body_onload();'>
<h4>
    Это пример, казалось бы, простой функциональности
</h4>
</body>
</html>

Этот пример выводит alert при заходе на страницу. При этом добавление "тела" скрипта происходит my_script.innerText=... или my_script.innerHTML=... , а запуск скрипта происходит "в синхронном стиле", без ожидания какого либо события, вызовом myScriptFunction();
